# MyCommand's Source vs Path

Tags: powershell

Under what circumstances does [`$MyInvocation.MyCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.externalscriptinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0)'s [`.Source`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.externalscriptinfo.source?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-externalscriptinfo-source) differ from [`.Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.externalscriptinfo.path?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-externalscriptinfo-path)?

One "Gets the path to the script file." whilst the other "Gets the source of this command." according to the docs, but whenever I've ever seen one populated the other has the same value.

Is this just a coincidence with this specific automatic variable and other `ExternalScriptInfo`s are more complex?

Comment: What makes you think that `$MyInvocation.MyCommand` is always an instance of `ExternalScriptInfo`? Try `&{$MyInvocation.MyCommand}|Get-Member` directly in your shell :)

Comment: Isn't `$MyInvocation` in the shell basically a dummy object and not really useful for anything? Even inside a block it's still returning dual blanks for the two properties. Regardless of the subclass for `CommandInfo`, what's the difference between `Source` & `Path`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I mean it just begs the question (since `ScriptInfo` doesn't even contain a `Path`), why do `ApplicationInfo` & `ExternalScriptInfo` have `Path`? If it's just an alias for `Source`, why isn't that in the docs?

Comment: `ApplicationInfo` and `ExternalScriptInfo` instances contain information about _files on disk_ - files have paths :) `ScriptInfo` contains information about code that exists in memory - hence no Path

Comment: Yes but the `Source` for code coming from disk are obviously naturally filesystem related.. why is a `Path` even necessary. Is `Source` *ever* a different value for these objects?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen might it be a historical thing where the `Path` subclasses were made first, then the abstracted file-less versions and super-class, where "path" wasn't appropriate and thus `Source` was introduced, but for compatibility `Path` was kept? Or is it more of a deliberate duck-typing attempt, where a coder can test if `Path` exists and know it's a file, without using reflective class-detection?

Comment: For an `ExternalScriptInfo` instance, they'll _never_ differ. [`Source` actually returns the `Definition`, with in turn returns the `Path`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/ExternalScriptInfo.cs#L145-L166). `Source` and `Definition` are present because they're part of the superclass (`CommandInfo`)

Comment: And I assume `ApplicationInfo` is the same? In this case do you happen to know *why* they have a `Path` at all, it's redundant? I dont think any consumer of these classes would have minded if the API only had `Source` for on-disk `CommandInfo`s too. That'd basically fully answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, for `ExternalScriptInfo` instances, the `Path`, `Source` and `Definition` properties always return the underlying path - as can be verified by inspecting the [source code here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c740a07e10b6f8a01a14104ec93db51274f67f9c/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/ExternalScriptInfo.cs#L138-L159).

The same goes [for `ApplicationInfo`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c740a07e10b6f8a01a14104ec93db51274f67f9c/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/ApplicationInfo.cs#L71-L85).

Comment: Are you able to answer why this was done? It seems silly.

Comment: @Hashbrown I'm not sure I can give a definitive answer, but the current layout/architecture is from PowerShell 3.0 - probably some things they got wrong in 2.0 had to be "fixed" without breaking API compatibility with scripts written for 2.0, so you end up with redundant information like this :)

Comment: Yeah I supposed that in our chat. I think I'll just use .Source and keep everything consistent.